# How to check if my input file is valid and existed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, fs

I am getting strings from a text file in Javascript.
I just want to show a message whenever the user enters the wrong file name or invalid file name.
like this: console.log("You input is invalid");
My code to read my text file and transfer the data to my variable is as follow:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var strings = [];
strings = fs.readFileSync('abc.txt','utf8');
```

I don't know how to check the existence of the file and put it in an if-else statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [existsSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const filePath = './file.txt';

try {
  if (fs.existsSync( filePath )) {
    // TASK TO PERFORM IF FILE EXISTS
    console.log("File exists.");
  } else {
  
  // TASK TO PERFORM IF FILE DOESN'T EXISTS
    console.log("Your input is invalid");
  }
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow code to check existence of file:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = 'abc.txt';

try { 
   if(fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
      // exist
   } else {
      // not found
   }
} catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
}
```